# Unable to Insert Casted XML Data into New Column in Temporary Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, insert, temporary-tables

### Question

How can I insert `CAST(event_data as XML)` data into a newly added column in a temporary table with the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO #Unique_Logins (event_data_xml) SELECT CAST(event_data AS XML) FROM #Unique_Logins
```

...without receiving the following error message:

> ```
> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 36
> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'module_guid', table 'tempdb.dbo.#Unique_Logins______________________________________________________________________________________________________00000000000F'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
> The statement has been terminated.
> ```

### Steps to Reproduce

I am trying to read some XML from an imported XEL file. In doing so I have to create a new column to convert the data from `nvarchar(max)` to `XML`.

### 1. Let's see how we can import an extended event log file

```
sp_help fn_xe_file_target_read_file
```

#### General Info

> ```
> Name                        | Owner   | Type            | Created_datetime
> ----------------------------+---------+-----------------+------------------
> fn_xe_file_target_read_file | sys     | inline function | 2014-02-20 20:48:46.370
> ```

#### Columns of inline function

> ```
> Column_name  | Type             | Computed | Length | Prec  | Scale | Nullable | TrimTrailingBlanks | FixedLenNullInSource | Collation
> -------------+------------------+----------+--------+-------+-------+----------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------------------
> module_guid  | uniqueidentifier | no       | 16     |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL
> package_guid | uniqueidentifier | no       | 16     |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL
> object_name  | nvarchar         | no       | 120    |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
> event_data   | nvarchar         | no       | -1     |       |       | yes      | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
> file_name    | nvarchar         | no       | 520    |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
> file_offset  | bigint           | no       | 8      | 19    | 0     | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL
> ```

#### Parameters of inline function

> ```
> Parameter_name     | Type     | Length | Prec | Scale | Param_order | Collation
> -------------------+----------+--------+------+-------+-------------+----------------
> @path              | nvarchar | 520    | 260  | NULL  | 1           | Latin1_General_CS_AS
> @mdpath            | nvarchar | 520    | 260  | NULL  | 2           | Latin1_General_CS_AS
> @initial_file_name | nvarchar | 520    | 260  | NULL  | 3           | Latin1_General_CS_AS
> @initial_offset    | bigint   | 8      | 19   | 0     | 4           | NULL
> ```

### 2. Insert data from XEL file into temporary table #Unique_Logins

```
select * into #Unique_Logins from sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(N'C:\temp\Unique_Logins_0_132175196428210000.xel',NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

> **Caution:**
>   I imported a **2 GB XEL file** which resulted in a **24 GB temporary table**!

### 3. Select from temporary table to see what columns we have

```
select TOP 2 * from #Unique_Logins
```

> ```
> module_guid                          | package_guid                         | object_name | event_data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | file_name                                      | file_offset
> -------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------
> CE79811F-1A80-40E1-8F5D-7445A3F375E7 | 655FD93F-3364-40D5-B2BA-330F7FFB6491 | login       | <event name="login" package="sqlserver" timestamp="2019-11-06T13:14:02.835Z">...<action name="database_name" package="sqlserver"><value><![CDATA[DatabaseName1]]></value></action>...<action name="server_principal_name" package="sqlserver"><value><![CDATA[DB_USER1]]></value></action>...</event> | C:\temp\Unique_Logins_0_132175196428210000.xel | 6656
> CE79811F-1A80-40E1-8F5D-7445A3F375E7 | 655FD93F-3364-40D5-B2BA-330F7FFB6491 | login       | <event name="login" package="sqlserver" timestamp="2019-11-06T13:14:02.894Z">...<action name="database_name" package="sqlserver"><value><![CDATA[DatabaseName2]]></value></action>...<action name="server_principal_name" package="sqlserver"><value><![CDATA[DB_USER2]]></value></action>...</event> | C:\temp\Unique_Logins_0_132175196428210000.xel | 6656
> ```

Now the data seems to be XML. Let's verify that it has been imported as XML.

### 4. Retrieve temporary table attributes

```
USE TEMPDB --caution; temporary table is in tempdb
GO
SELECT sc.name, 
       st.name, 
       st.max_length, 
       st.collation_name, 
       sc.column_id, 
       sc.collation_name, 
       sc.max_length, 
       sc.is_nullable, 
       sc.is_xml_document
FROM sys.columns AS sc JOIN sys.types AS st 
    ON sc.user_type_id = st.user_type_id WHERE sc.object_id = OBJECT_ID('#Unique_Logins')
```

> ```
> name         | name             | max_length | collation_name       | column_id | collation_name       | max_length | is_nullable | is_xml_document
> -------------+------------------+------------+----------------------+-----------+----------------------+------------+-------------+----------------
> module_guid  | uniqueidentifier | 16         | NULL                 | 1         | NULL                 | 16         | 0           | 0
> package_guid | uniqueidentifier | 16         | NULL                 | 2         | NULL                 | 16         | 0           | 0
> object_name  | nvarchar         | 8000       | Latin1_General_CS_AS | 3         | Latin1_General_CS_AS | 120        | 0           | 0
> event_data   | nvarchar         | 8000       | Latin1_General_CS_AS | 4         | Latin1_General_CS_AS | -1         | 1           | 0
> file_name    | nvarchar         | 8000       | Latin1_General_CS_AS | 5         | Latin1_General_CS_AS | 520        | 0           | 0
> file_offset  | bigint           | 8          | NULL                 | 6         | NULL                 | 8          | 0           | 0
> ```

The XML data in the column `event_data` has been imported to a `nvarchar(max)` column.

### 5. Create new column `event_data_xml` as XML and insert column data from `event_data` using `CAST()`

```
ALTER TABLE #Unique_Logins ADD event_data_xml XML
GO
INSERT INTO #Unique_Logins (event_data_xml) SELECT CAST(event_data AS XML) FROM #Unique_Logins
```

### Error Message

> ```
> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 36
> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'module_guid', table 'tempdb.dbo.#Unique_Logins______________________________________________________________________________________________________00000000000F'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
> The statement has been terminated.
> ```

I don't see what `module_guid` has to do with the INSERT / SELECT statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INSERT will create a new data-set in your table - as you demand that

```
Column_name  | Type             | Computed | Length | Prec  | Scale | Nullable | TrimTrailingBlanks | FixedLenNullInSource | Collation
-------------+------------------+----------+--------+-------+-------+----------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------------------
module_guid  | uniqueidentifier | no       | 16     |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL
package_guid | uniqueidentifier | no       | 16     |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL
object_name  | nvarchar         | no       | 120    |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
event_data   | nvarchar         | no       | -1     |       |       | yes      | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
file_name    | nvarchar         | no       | 520    |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
file_offset  | bigint           | no       | 8      | 19    | 0     | no       | (n/a)
```

among other columns module_guid shall not contain NULL .. you have to specify a value for  this and all other not null columns ... hence the error message

I assume you better use an update statement, when you want to add those XML-data to an existing data-set.

e.g.

```
UPDATE #Unique_Logins SET event_data_xml = CAST(event_data AS XML)
```

Comment: True - but I suppose the guid-columns are references to modules-table and package-table .. and his existing data show that they exist ... -> update

Comment: So this must be one of those face-palm moments. I didn't see the obvious. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I can confirm that running `UPDATE #Unique_Logins SET event_data_xml = CAST(event_data AS XML)` returns as ***Command(s) completed successfully.*** Thanks again for pointing out the obvious.